# how to show sphere rotation on a 2d plane

Tags: animation, gtk, geometry, game-physics, projection

I am trying to make a pool game with C and GTK+3.0
game is top-view so there are some circles as pool balls.
I've set image to each circle with Gtk.
now somehow I want to show sphere rotation in my 2D game. I guess there is some tricks with changing the image while moving the ball but I don't know exactly what to do!
I just want my circles seems like 3D sphere when they move. have any idea?

Comment: Please read the help section of this site: your question doesn't describe a specific coding problem, it doesn't contain valid code to reproduce the problem, nor does it show any attempts you've made to solve the problem. Answering this question is a bit like a blind child, co-piloting a ufo trying to land on the dark side of the moon. (PS: you're creating a 2D game, but want it to look 3D? Why not make it 3D to begin with?)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the game development subsection: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

If the balls have only one color, then what can convey the notion of motion is either the change of lights (better done in 3D), or the rotation of the number on the ball.

Give a look here to see what was done a few years back on the Amiga computer:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTQIPFBUFIg